# Data Analysis Scala on Spark

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I am new to Scala, and i have to use Scala and Spark's SQL, Mllib and GraphX in order to perform some analysis on huge data set. The analyses i want to do are:

- Customer life cycle Value (CLV)
- Centrality measures (degree, Eigenvector, edge-betweenness,
  closeness) The data is in a CSV file (60GB (3 years transnational data))
  located in Hadoop cluster.

My question is about the optimal approach to access the data and perform the above calculations?

- Should i load the data from the CSV file into dataframe and work on
  the dataframe? or
- Should i load the data from the CSV file and convert it into RDD and
  then work on the RDD? or
- Are there any other approach to access the data and perform the analyses?

Thank you so much in advance for your help..

Answer (score 1):

Dataframe gives you sql like syntax to work with the data where as RDD gives Scala collection like methods for data manipulation.

One extra benefit with Dataframes is underlying spark system will optimise your queries just like sql query optimisation. This is not available in case of RDD's.

As you are new to Scala its highly recommended to use Dataframes API initially and then Pick up RDD API later based on requirement.

Comment: The somewhat typesafe version of dataframes are datasets, which are the recommended API because of better data compression. For the typesafe issue there's https://github.com/adelbertc/frameless/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Databricks CSV reader` api, which is easy to use and returns `DataFrame`. It automatically infer data types. If you pass the file with header it can automatically use that as Schema, otherwise you can construct schema using `StructType`.

```
https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv
```

**Update:**
If you are using Spark 2.0 Version , by default it support CSV datasource, please see the below link.

https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-0-0.html#new-features

See this link for how to use.
https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/367